# EventSource vs EventProvider

Tags: c#, .net, etw, event-viewer

What are the main differences between the [EventSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource(v=vs.110).aspx) and [EventProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.eventprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) classes?

I understand both classes to be an event provider for ETW. If there aren't key differences in the two then what are the pros and cons.

I use the EventSource class simply because I found more examples/documentation online, and it seemed more straightforward to implement Channel support (writing to the default channels in the Event Viewer - admin, operational, analytic, and debug) because the EventRegister class automatically creates the manifest (described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2013/08/09/announcing-the-eventsource-nuget-package-write-to-the-windows-event-log/)).

Comment: good question. looks like the Provider class was the first try to make ETW usable in .net (added in 3.5, while EventSource was added with 4.5). But is is only speculation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 the `EventProvider` class was the only option for tracing using ETW. As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventing.eventprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) states, you must create an Instrumentation Manifest file for your custom events, which describes the data types inside your messages. This is not such easy task, and it requires using separate tools, such as the Manifest Generator (ecmangen.exe). For more information, please see [this post](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/creating-strongly-typed-c-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-assemblies-with-visual-studio/).

The `EventSource` class was added in .NET 4.5 and it introduced a [simpler approach](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2012/07/09/introduction-tutorial-logging-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource/) to writing your own events using ETW. Instead of creating these manifest files, they are automatically created for you, sparing the overhead.

I don't see any reason to use `EventProvider` given the above. As you mentioned, `EventSource` is more documented and much easier to use.